# Angularjs passing functions with arguments to directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive called `table-element` I am calling like this...

```
<div ng-controller="Test as ctrl">
    <table-element edit="ctrl.editfun(ctrl.arg, 'edit')" remove="ctrl.remfun(ctrl.arg, 'rem')">
        <h3>transcluded content</h3>
    </table-element>    
</div>
```

I am passing two functions, `edit` and `remove` to the directive with arguments  supplied (`ctrl.arg`, `edit` and `remove`). To my surprise, in the directive `link` function I can call...

```
$scope.onClickEdit = function() {
  $scope.edit();
};

$scope.onClickDelete = function() {             
  $scope.remove();
};
```

And the functions are still called with the correct arguments. I'm new to Javascript and I don't understand why this works. Can someone explain what happens when `$scope.edit()` is called, i.e. how the arguments get discovered/passed when the functions are called in the link function? And are there any potential problems with calling methods like this? (here is the full [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kergoog/whvctzvn/50/)).

Comment: Just read documentation it's well explained there in section for directive/compile.

Comment: So am I right in thinking that `$scope.edit()` actually evaluates to the 'expression' `ctrl.editfun(ctrl.arg, 'edit')` in the context of the controller scope? - as per 'https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive'

Comment: Yes, you are right. it's done with `&` in scope config.

Comment: Okay thanks. I wrongly thought this evaluated to a function not an expression. That's pretty powerful.